# NSFileManager: duplicate file if exists

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

I'd like to have OSX-behaviour in my iOS-App when copying files: if it exists, append a counter to it:

- myFile.png => myFile 1.png
- myFile20.png => myFile20 1.png
- myFile 20.png => myFile 21.png
- ...

Is there a built-in way to do this or do I have to build that functionality myself? I couldn't find anything like that but I don't think I'm the first one needing this behaviour...

Comment: You have to do that yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this, where `requestedName` is the file name the user selected, `extension` is the extension of the file and `basePath` is the folder you're trying to store it in:

```
 NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
 NSString * filename = requestedName;

 if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:[basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:requestedName]]) 
{   
     unsigned int counter = 1;
     while ( [fm fileExistsAtPath: [basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent: filename]]) 
     {
         //NSLog(@"File already exists %@", filename);
         NSURL *originalFilePath = [NSURL URLWithString:[kTempPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename]];
         filename = [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@-%d",
         [requestedName stringByDeletingPathExtension], counter]stringByAppendingPathExtension: extension];
         counter ++;
         NSURL *newFilePath = [NSURL URLWithString:[kTempPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename]];
         [fm moveItemAtURL:originalFilePath toURL:newFilePath error:nil]; 
      // just in case
         if (counter > 512) break;
     }
}
```

if the file doesn't exist then just move it to the correct location using `moveItemAtURL`or `moveItemAtPath`from the NSFileManager.

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the source file name,and use the name as the source path last component.
just like this:

```
-(XMPFile*) duplicateDocument:(XMPFile*)file error:(NSError **)error
{
    NSString *filePath = [file path];
    NSString *destinationPath = [[file path] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
    NSString *pathExtension = [filePath pathExtension];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *fileName = [[[file path] lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];

    unsigned int counter = 2;

    while ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
    {
        NSString *duplicatedFilePathLastComponent = [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %d", fileName, counter] stringByAppendingPathExtension: pathExtension];

        NSString *duplicatedFilePath = [destinationPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:duplicatedFilePathLastComponent];

        if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:destinationPath]) {
            if ([fileManager copyItemAtPath:filePath toPath:duplicatedFilePath error:error]) {
                XMPFile *duplicatedXMPFile = [[XMPFile alloc] initWithPath:duplicatedFilePath];
                return duplicatedXMPFile;
            }
        }

        counter ++;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

If you want,you can add error message also

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any in built mechanism in NSFileManager. Most probably you will need to implement your own by inspecting error type. If error is of kind 'already exists' then try to append appropriate counter and copy.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported by iOS.

You will need to generate the random counter (probably time tick) and append it to file name.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that there are several answers here already but I felt mine was a bit more straight forward than the ones provided.

I needed to solve this problem too. I just defined a function so it could be unit tested easily.

```
- (NSString*)findNextValidFilePathAt:(NSString*)destination
                        withFileName:(NSString*)fileName
{
    NSFileManager* filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString* newFilePath = [destination stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    NSString* originalFilePathWithoutExtension = [newFilePath stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSString* pathExtension = [fileName pathExtension];
    int numberToAppend = 0;

    while ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:newFilePath] && numberToAppend <= 99)
    {
        // find a new file path to try: <original_path> <number>.<extension>
        // Ex: /users/alex/desktop/image 1.png
        numberToAppend++;
        newFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d.%@",
                       originalFilePathWithoutExtension,
                       numberToAppend,
                       pathExtension];
    }

    return newFilePath;
}
```